# jooq use oracle text contains query

Tags: java, jooq

I am building a query using jooq and need to add a condition to where clause using oracle text..
So far I have a collection of conditions that I build up and use to build the query at the end...

```
List<Condition> conditions = new ArrayList<Condition>();
if(null != searchCriteria.getId()) {
    conditions.add(field("id").eq(searchCriteria.getId()));
} else if(null != searchCriteria.getSurname()) {
    //add contains condition here. e.g. "CONTAINS (SURNAME, 'POTTER', 1) > 0
}
```

I can't see how to build this condition or at least manually build this SQL string and then add as condition to then generate the full query like...

```
org.jooq.Query ps = select(field("ID")).from(table("PERSON per").where(conditions);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already used the [plain SQL templating](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/) feature in your other parts of the query, perhaps inadvertently. Now you can use it to build vendor specific syntax extensions directly in jOOQ. For example:

```java
static Condition contains(Field<String> field, String search, int label) {
    return condition("contains({0}, {1}, {2}) > 0", field, val(search), inline(label));
}
```

In the above example, I'm using [`DSL.condition(String, Object...)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#condition-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-)

Comment: Cheers for this answer @Lukas Eder, only thing I found was I was unable to have a bind variable for the score label value. I get ORA-29909: label for the ancillary operator is not a literal number. I had to hard code this value for it to work, anybody know a work around.

Comment: Sorry to keep asking but how would I build up a from clause dynamically with table joins as is possible with where clause.. or should I ask another question? I have a search query that is built up dynamically and if a search param exists I need to add table join.. but I'd like to create a list of joins to be added to query at the end.

Comment: @jonesy: Please ask a new question